# To validate the client or app time is matched with internet time

Tags: java, php, angularjs

We have API to validate client's time using PHP.
For now our server time is MYT(Kuala Lumpur).

Since our client is around the world, we keep track their apps transaction and having local time(device time).

Example API request: `device_time = '2016-10-15 02:04:06 +01:00'`

1. What is the best implementation so that we will keep the correct time in MYT.
2. How to detect mismatced time especially the device does not matched with internet time

Comment: Use UTC for everything

Comment: For all intents and purposes you can't.  Most businesses use a universal timezone (typically UTC) and simply keep track of the timezone the client is reporting it's in if it's necessary to know that.